# How to formulate the minimum and maximum range of possible values?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

In Store $X$, shelf 1 accounted for $\frac{1}{4}$ of Bakery $C$ 's average weekly sales and shelf 2 accounted for $\frac{2}{3}$ as much as shelf 1 . If shelves 3 and 4 each accounted for less than shelf 2 but together accounted for more than shelf 1, what's the maximum and minimum range of possible average weekly sales in shelf five?

How to formulate this problem as a linear programming problem?

Comment: Hint: introduce nonnegative decision variable $x_i$ to represent the sales in shelf $i$, where $i\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.  Also, you probably want to interpret "less than" as $\le$ and "more than" as $\ge$..

Comment: With no other information, the minimum is zero and the maximum is unbounded. I'm sure that there's a significant section of the problem you haven't shown us.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4688985/max-and-minimum-remaining-given-inequality-constraint

Comment: An answer was posted by @Sutanu on Math SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4689015/458896

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make some sweeping assumptions:

- As @RobPratt says, assume that all open inequalities are actually closed inequalities
- Assume that total sales are fixed at 1.0, meaning that the shelf quantities are represented as fractions of the actual total sales
- Assume that there are no other shelves, which was not explicit in the question
- Assume that amortized sales averages are not e.g. per unit of bread, but in cash; in other words, all variables continuous instead of integral

Run the same problem twice: once for each of 'minimize' and 'maximize'. Most software can do this conversion for you, but if not, then just negate the objective the second time through.

An example implementation in PuLP shows that the fifth shelf varies between 25% and 33.33% of total weekly sales.

```py
from typing import Literal
import pulp


'''
In Store X, shelf 1 accounted for 1/4 of Bakery C's average weekly sales and shelf 2 accounted for
2/3 as much as shelf 1. If shelves 3 and 4 each accounted for less than shelf 2, but together 
accounted for more than shelf 1, what's the maximum and minimum, range of possible average weekly 
sales in shelf five?
'''


def run_with_sense(sense: Literal['Minimize', 'Maximize']) -> list[float]:
    total = pulp.LpVariable(
        name='total',
        # In the absense of any other information, fix the total at 1 so that the solution is
        # fractional
        lowBound=1, upBound=1)

    shelves = [
        pulp.LpVariable(name=f'shelf_{i}', lowBound=0)
        for i in range(1, 6)
    ]

    prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='bakery', sense=getattr(pulp, 'Lp' + sense))
    prob.objective = shelves[4] + 0

    # Assume that the sum of five shelves account for total sales
    # (this is left ambiguous in the question)
    prob.addConstraint(name='sales_total', constraint=total == pulp.lpSum(shelves))

    # shelf 1 accounted for 1/4 of Bakery C's average weekly sales
    prob.addConstraint(name='sales_1', constraint=4*shelves[0] == total)

    # shelf 2 accounted for 2/3 as much as shelf 1
    prob.addConstraint(name='sales_1_2', constraint=2*shelves[0] == 3*shelves[1])

    # shelves 3 and 4 each accounted for less than shelf 2
    # ("less" is only approximated here as "at most")
    prob.addConstraint(name='sales_3_2', constraint=shelves[2] <= shelves[1])
    prob.addConstraint(name='sales_4_2', constraint=shelves[3] <= shelves[1])

    # together accounted for more than shelf 1
    # ("more" is only approximated here as "at least")
    prob.addConstraint(name='sales_3_4_1', constraint=shelves[2] + shelves[3] >= shelves[0])

    print(prob)
    prob.solve()
    assert prob.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal
    return [v.value() for v in shelves]


def main() -> None:
    for sense in ('Minimize', 'Maximize'):
        shelf_fractions = run_with_sense(sense)
        print('Shelf fractions of total sales:')
        print(', '.join(f'{s:.4f}' for s in shelf_fractions))
        print()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
bakery:
MINIMIZE
1*shelf_5 + 0
SUBJECT TO
sales_total: - shelf_1 - shelf_2 - shelf_3 - shelf_4 - shelf_5 + total = 0

sales_1: 4 shelf_1 - total = 0

sales_1_2: 2 shelf_1 - 3 shelf_2 = 0

sales_3_2: - shelf_2 + shelf_3 <= 0

sales_4_2: - shelf_2 + shelf_4 <= 0

sales_3_4_1: - shelf_1 + shelf_3 + shelf_4 >= 0

VARIABLES
shelf_1 Continuous
shelf_2 Continuous
shelf_3 Continuous
shelf_4 Continuous
shelf_5 Continuous
total = 1 Continuous

Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.10.3 
Build Date: Dec 15 2019 

command line - pulp.sol (default strategy 1)
At line 2 NAME          MODEL
At line 3 ROWS
At line 11 COLUMNS
At line 30 RHS
At line 37 BOUNDS
At line 39 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 6 rows, 6 columns and 17 elements
Coin0008I MODEL read with 0 errors
Option for timeMode changed from cpu to elapsed
Presolve 0 (-6) rows, 0 (-6) columns and 0 (-17) elements
Empty problem - 0 rows, 0 columns and 0 elements
Optimal - objective value 0.25
After Postsolve, objective 0.25, infeasibilities - dual 0 (0), primal 0 (0)
Optimal objective 0.25 - 0 iterations time 0.002, Presolve 0.00
Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.00   (Wallclock seconds):       0.00

Shelf fractions of total sales:
0.2500, 0.1667, 0.1667, 0.1667, 0.2500

bakery:
MAXIMIZE
1*shelf_5 + 0
SUBJECT TO
sales_total: - shelf_1 - shelf_2 - shelf_3 - shelf_4 - shelf_5 + total = 0

sales_1: 4 shelf_1 - total = 0

sales_1_2: 2 shelf_1 - 3 shelf_2 = 0

sales_3_2: - shelf_2 + shelf_3 <= 0

sales_4_2: - shelf_2 + shelf_4 <= 0

sales_3_4_1: - shelf_1 + shelf_3 + shelf_4 >= 0

VARIABLES
shelf_1 Continuous
shelf_2 Continuous
shelf_3 Continuous
shelf_4 Continuous
shelf_5 Continuous
total = 1 Continuous

Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.10.3 
Build Date: Dec 15 2019 

command line - pulp.sol (default strategy 1)
At line 2 NAME          MODEL
At line 3 ROWS
At line 11 COLUMNS
At line 30 RHS
At line 37 BOUNDS
At line 39 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 6 rows, 6 columns and 17 elements
Coin0008I MODEL read with 0 errors
Option for timeMode changed from cpu to elapsed
Presolve 0 (-6) rows, 0 (-6) columns and 0 (-17) elements
Empty problem - 0 rows, 0 columns and 0 elements
Optimal - objective value 0.33333333
After Postsolve, objective 0.33333333, infeasibilities - dual 0 (0), primal 0 (0)
Optimal objective 0.3333333333 - 0 iterations time 0.002, Presolve 0.00
Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.00   (Wallclock seconds):       0.00

Shelf fractions of total sales:
0.2500, 0.1667, 0.0833, 0.1667, 0.3333
```

But note the output describing that the problem is trivial:

```
Presolve 0 (-6) rows, 0 (-6) columns and 0 (-17) elements
Empty problem - 0 rows, 0 columns and 0 elements
```

It's just as easy to solve this problem by hand:

$$s_1 = \frac 1 4$$
$$s_2 = \frac 2 3 s_1 = \frac 1 6$$
Let $s_3 = s_4 = s_{34}$, then
$$ \frac 1 2 \cdot \frac 1 4 \le s_{34} \le \frac 1 6 $$
$$ \frac 1 8 \le \frac 1 2 \left( 1 - \frac 1 4 - \frac 1 6 - s_5 \right) \le \frac 1 6 $$
$$ \frac 1 8 \le \frac 7 {24} - \frac {s_5} 2 \le \frac 1 6 $$
$$ \frac 1 4 \le s_5 \le \frac 1 3 $$